# Could not find androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, build.gradle

I am a newbie programmer, lately i decided to return a project i abondeded a while ago because of some of my other projects. The problem is whenever i do this kind of things i am having a lot of problems with my gradle/ android studio files as it is constantly upgrading, changing files. To fix the issues i changed my targetsdk, midsdk versions in my gradle files and tried to changed the some of the implentations but no luck. Now i am getting the fallowing errors when i try to rebuild/remake my project

```
6: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
   > Could not find androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03 > androidx.activity:activity:1.6.0-alpha03
   > Could not find androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4
         project :app > androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1
   > Could not find androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03 > androidx.drawerlayout:drawerlayout:1.0.0
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0 > androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 > androidx.media:media:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1 > androidx.customview:customview:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6 > androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1 > com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0
         project :app > com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0 > androidx.dynamicanimation:dynamicanimation:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.slidingpanelayout:slidingpanelayout:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0
         project :app > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0 > androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-ui:1.0.0 > androidx.asynclayoutinflater:asynclayoutinflater:1.0.0
         project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1 > com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.1.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement:21.1.1 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:21.1.1
   > Could not find androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03 > androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.6.0-alpha03
         project :app > com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0 > androidx.transition:transition:1.2.0
   > Could not find androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03 > androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.2.0-alpha04
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03 > androidx.emoji2:emoji2-views-helper:1.2.0-alpha04
   > Could not find androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://maven.fabric.io/public/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/core/core/1.12.0-alpha02/core-1.12.0-alpha02.pom
     Required by:
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03 > androidx.fragment:fragment:1.3.6
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:18.2.0
         project :app > com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0 > com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.1.0
         project :app > androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03 >
```

My project gradle file is like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

My app gradle file is like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdk 33
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.bogroup.ilkprogram"
        minSdkVersion 33
        //noinspection EditedTargetSdkVersion
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 100
        versionName "1.0.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
        // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
        // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
        // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
        exclude 'META-INF/notice'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.bogroup.ilkprogram'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
}
ext {
    googlePlayVer = "10.2.0"
}
dependencies {
    def core_version = "1.12.0-alpha02"
    // Java language implementation
    implementation "androidx.core:core:$core_version"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.5.0"

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1"
    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Realtime Database
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Firestore
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Firebase Auth
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:8.0.2'

    // FirebaseUI for Cloud Storage
    //implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:8.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:33.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:33.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:33.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:33.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:33.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:33.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Any help is greatly apprciated, also what will be the correct way to return to an old project like this. I know even i fix this with your helps, i will have problems again if i give a break and then return to my project after 6 months or a year.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, it looks like `androidx.core:core:1.12.0-alpha02` is missing from [Google's Maven repository](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html#androidx.core:core). I do not know why that would have happened.

A minimally-invasive solution may be to request `1.12.0-alpha03` via:

```
def core_version = "1.12.0-alpha03"
```

Even better will be to upgrade `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0-alpha03` to `1.6.0` or `1.6.1`, as we are past the alpha period for AppCompat 1.6.0.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply however when i change these i am getting the fallowing errors;   1.  Dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha03' requires libraries and applications that
      depend on it to compile against codename "UpsideDownCake" of the
      Android APIs.

      :app is currently compiled against android-33.

      Recommended action: Use a different version of dependency 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0-alpha03',
      or set compileSdkPreview to "UpsideDownCake" in your build.gradle
      file if you intend to experiment with that preview SDK.

Comment: @Faruk: Update your `compileSdk` to `34`.